# ASP.NET hello world AJAX post

Tags: asp.net

I keep getting a 500 with the following C#/jQuery. Any given implementation may not be right and thats not a huge issue. I'm just trying to get a hello world up. It works if the c# has no arguments but as soon as I try to recieve data it gives the 500.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test(string s)
{
    // never gets here
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.aspx/" + method,
    /*async: true,*/
    data: "{data:'" + data + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data.d);
    }
});
```

latest attempt is this which still doesnt work:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string Test(string data)
{
    // never gets here
    return "hello world";
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
    data: "data: {data:'abc'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("back");
    }
});
```

Comment: how do you set `data`? in `data: "{data:'" + data + "'}"`

Comment: the data variable is a string with no quotes around it. ie data is --> abcdefg

Comment: What URL you are using to try to reach that controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to use MVC to make it work. I think the way you are passing json parameters are wrong. Please check below code and try and do let me know whether it works.

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string Test(string data)
{
  // never gets here
  return "hello world";
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
    data:'{"data":"abc"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Finally got it to work using that. [WebMethod] worked without the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string x)
{
    // never gets here
    return Json(true)
}

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "ajax/Test",
    data: {x:'abc'},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       alert("back");
    }
});
```

Comment: not sure but change the parameter name, make it `data: {s : "abc"}`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  http://localhost:16679/ajax.aspx/Test

Comment: i found that too. ........and its not built in. so ill now branch off and try to install mvc and then see how it fails... #!@$#@$#$@ waste of time.

Comment: k atually it was installed i just had to add a reference....... still did nothing - http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l493/powerfulcrunch/nope.png