# Use jQuery in code behind - callback refreshes page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, code-behind

This sounds easy, but I've been struggling with it all morning.

I have an asp.Net page and a corresponding code behind page. My user enters a new password and then the code behind page checks to see if it's OK (long enough, some regex to check for disallowed characters, etc.). If the password is OK, code behind performs sql query to update the database.

If the query is successful, I want to  hide the password-input div and show the password-successfully-create div, which gives my user further instructions. I've always done this easily in php using jQuery.

My problem: the work I just described is all done on the server side. I can send the appropriate jQuery script back to the client side using a ClientScriptManager (RegisterStartupScript). Fine and dandy, but the call back to the server refreshes the page, so the page refreshes and reverts back to the original appearance. If you look closely, you can see the divs hiding and showing the way I want, but in a fraction of a second they go back to the way they were originally- I assume because the callback is refreshing the page.

Is it possible to show/hide DOM elements from the code behind page when a call to the server is being executed? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

It's the asp:button control itself that's the issue. I get the same behavior in the following code, which doesn't use the code behind page at all. If I replace the asp:button control with a normal HTML input control, it works fine.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

       $('document').ready(function () {

        $('.MyButton').click(function () {
            $('#MyTable').toggle();
        })

    })

</script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" class="MyButton" />

<table id="MyTable" >
    <tr>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>is</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714019/asp-net-hello-world-ajax-post

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind use something like:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    // show/hide elements you need based on the processing results
}
```

This is assuming your elements to show/hide are actually ASP.NET controls. If not you can always enclose them in `<asp:Panel>` controls and manage what's being displayed that way.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Good suggestion, but it turns out that the asp:button (with the runat="server") attribute does it all by itself. I've edited my question with an example.